# Gaussian integral on arbitrary semi-plan

Tags: gaussian-integral

Does somebody know if there's somewhat an analytical solution to the Gaussian integral on a semi-plan:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x<c}e^{-\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{2}}dxdy$

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^c \int_{-\infty}^c e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} dxdy$ you want to find an analytical solution to?

Comment: No, $y$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, but actually I think my question if pretty dumb as the integral is separable...

Comment: Yes exactly, and then your integral is simply equal to $\int_{-\infty}^c e^{-\frac{x^2}2} dx$, which can not be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Thanks, but I can use the $erf$ function, right? Which is available in numerical packages.